# Average of multiple dataframes with the same columns and indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few dataframes. Each of them has the same columns and the same indices. For each index I want to average the values in each column (if these would be matrices, I would just sum them up and divide by the number of matrices).

Here is the example.

```
v1 = pd.DataFrame([['ind1', 1, 2, 3], ['ind2', 4, 5, 6]], columns=['id', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']).set_index('id')
v2 = pd.DataFrame([['ind1', 2, 3, 4], ['ind2', 6, 1, 2]], columns=['id', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']).set_index('id')
v3 = pd.DataFrame([['ind1', 1, 2, 1], ['ind2', 1, 1, 3]], columns=['id', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']).set_index('id')
```

In real situation indices and columns can be in different order.

For this situation the result will be

[image]

(the value for ind1, c1 is `(1 + 1 + 2) / 3`, for ind2, c2 is `(1 + 5 + 1) / 3` and so on).

Currently I do this with loops:

```
dfs = [v1, v2, v3]
cols= ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

data = []
for ind, _ in dfs[0].iterrows():
    vals = [sum(df.loc[ind][col] for df in dfs) / float(len(dfs)) for col in cols]
    data.append([ind] + vals)

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id'] + cols).set_index('id')
```

, but this is clearly inefficient for big dataframes with a lot of columns. So how can I achieve this without loops?

Comment: You can still do (v1 + v2 + v3) / 3. Pandas works on the indices, the order is not important. Another alternative is panel `pd.Panel({'v1': v1, 'v2': v2, 'v3': v3}).mean(axis=0)` but I'd go with concat too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) on the `index` level after concatenating the dataframes:

```
pd.concat([v1, v2, v3]).groupby(level=0).mean()

            c1        c2        c3
id                                
ind1  1.333333  2.333333  2.666667
ind2  3.666667  2.333333  3.666667
```

Comment: I would add a rule of thumb to this - always prefer using the built-in pandas functions for sum, mean, etc. over your own code, as it's been thoroughly optimized for performance.

Comment: @Shovalt I know, this is why I was asking someone to tell me a proper solution. My loops were only to show what have I tried.

Comment: How one can avoid losing non-numeric columns using this method? i.e I have a mixed columns values and I wish to mean only the numeric ones?