# calculate mean of cells from different dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the mean of multiple cells from different dataframes. I have calculated the correlation between variables with `df.corr()` and I have to do this another 9 times and calculate the mean of correlation of each varaible.

For example, the first dataframe with correlations I got as a result could be this:

```
    a    b    c  
__________________

a  1   0.2   0.3

b  0.2   1   0.4

c  0.3   0.4  1
```

The second correlation dataframe could be this:

```
    a    b    c  
__________________

a  1   0.3   0.2

b  0.3   1   0.4

c  0.2  0.4  1
```

And I would like to obtain a final dataframe with the mean of each one of the cells considering all the dataframes.

```
df_result

    a    b    c  
__________________

a  1   0.25   0.25

b  0.25   1   0.4

c  0.25   0.4  1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Average of multiple dataframes with the same columns and indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940946/average-of-multiple-dataframes-with-the-same-columns-and-indices) Note how you should use the built-in pandas mean() method, which has better performance than if you implement your own formula for avraging.

Comment: It doesn't work in this case

Comment: I posted an answer below that applies the code from the stackoverflow link I provided to your problem. Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty forward, you could just do:

```py
(df1.corr() + df2.corr()) / 2
```

as the two dataframes have the same columns

Comment: And what should I do if I want to calcule de std of the values?

Comment: You mean the std per every two values, like the std of the two values vector, (for example for a, b, that would be the std of [0.25, 0.3]) ?

Comment: yes, it would be the std between [0.3, 0.2], between [0.4, 0.4]...

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [Average of multiple dataframes with the same columns and indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940946/average-of-multiple-dataframes-with-the-same-columns-and-indices), It's better to use the built-in pandas mean() method for better performance.

The following code will iterate through a number of randomly generated dataframes, append each of the correlation matrices to a list, then use the built-in mean() function to take the average.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
correlation_matrices = []

for _ in range(10):
    df = pd.DataFrame(rs.rand(3, 3))
    correlation_matrices.append(df.corr())

correlation = pd.concat(correlation_matrices).groupby(level=0)
mean_corr = correlation.mean()
std_corr = correlation.std()
```